# kamailio: how to extract IP from received route header

Tags: sip, kamailio, opensips

Could any help me to find way to extract IP & Port from route header received (which is on the SIP INVITE received from a remote server).

`KAMAILO ----> A Server`

A - Server is appending router header with destination IP address like below.

`A Server ----> KAMAILIO`

`Route: <sip:<KAMILIO IP (Unchanged)>:5060;lr>,<sip:<B-Server>:5060;lr>`

Here i need to extract the destination server (B-Server) IP & Port from received route header in the SIP INVITE.

`KAMAILI ----> B - Server`

i have found below from kamailio forum for extracting VIA header using select method, but i am not sure how to use the right variable for Route header.

```
    onreply_route[MANAGE_REPLY] {
    ...
    if(search_hf("Via", "received", "f")) {
            xdbg("received param exists on top most via header \n");
            $var(public_ip) = $sel(via.received);
        }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A note that the call scenario and requirement is not clear in my opinion.

But in general you can access the `Route` header of a message using `$hdr(Route)`, e.g.:

```
$var(the_route) = $hdr(Route);
```

That would give you the whole list, in case of comma separated values, so from your example `$var(the_route)` would contain `<sip:<KAMILIO IP (Unchanged)>:5060;lr>,<sip:<B-Server>:5060;lr>`.

After that you can parse it by splitting on the comma with something like:

```
$var(route0) = $(var(the_route){s.select,0,,});
$var(route1) = $(var(the_route){s.select,1,,});
```

You can use an index and loop through it until the extracted value will be an empty string.